# PHP file from .ajax call not inserting data into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I'm pretty new to PHP and I've never done AJAX before- I decided to use the Jquery .ajax function because it had more customizations than the .post one and because i like the succinctness of it over that of a regular javascript.

Here is the ajax code

```
    $("#upvotearrow").click(function() {
    var dataString="vote=upvote";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../secure/process_upvotedownvote.php",
        data: dataString
    })
    .done(function() {
        alert("Upvote registered!");
    });
});
```

And the external PHP file so far is this:

```
include "db_connect.php";
include "functions.php";


    if(isset($_POST['vote']) && !empty($_POST['vote'])) {
        $poemid=7;
        $typeofvote = $_POST['vote'];
        if ($typeofvote=="upvote") {
            if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE poems SET poem_upvotes=poem_upvotes+1 WHERE poem_id=?")) { //Prepare SQL statement
                $insert_stmt->bind_param('i',$poemid); //Bind parameters
                $insert_stmt->execute();// Execute the prepared query.
            }
        }
   }
```

The `$mysqli` variable is fine and the query works when I just type it in the database, so my question here is essentially if I'm transfering data from AJAX to PHP properly.

Also- a side question- is it possible for the PHP file I call to access variables from the URL of the page making the AJAX call? (I.E. the url is `http://website.com/poem_id=7` and I want to access the `poem_id` value?

Comment: You can access the `poem_id` by using `$_GET['poem_id']` for example.
`$poem_id = $_GET['poem_id'];`

Comment: So is the part in the PHP that is `  if(isset($_POST['vote']) && !empty($_POST['vote'])) {`  fine, or should it just be $_GET['vote'] instead of $_POST?

Comment: Parameters after `?` in the URL will be in `$_GET`, parameters in the `data:` option to `$.ajax` will be in `$_POST`. You can also use `$_REQUEST`, which combines them both.

Comment: Have you debugged to check which values are passed to your php page? And even if your if condition works?

Comment: I just changed the URL parameter in the .ajax function to just " secure/process_upvotedownvote.php" and Firebug didn't report any errors and the function still didn't work-- the function in .done was initiated even though the URL is wrong. I'm not quite sure what to make of this- any direction would be extremely helpful.

Comment: try `var dataString={};dataString.vote = 'upvote';` instead of `var dataString="vote=upvote";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses everyone-

I found out that Firebug doesn't show error reports for external PHP files, but Safari will echo variables out in the XHRs file in the Developer tools-

I then created a hidden input field with the poem_id data in it, checked that it was valid on the server side, then executed the script. I also fixed a syntax error which had been throwing the program off.

Thanks again for the replies- I'm learning a ton about AJAX by making my website and how to harness it's incredible power.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `print_r($_POST)` in the db insertion file and see if you are getting all the variables with proper name. As per the code, you should get.
Further more, you can pass any parameter that you do with normal urls the only difference it that it will be called with AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the value of `dataString` variable 
`var dataString = {vote:upvote};`